# Distribute data equally in all the bins based on a column : Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have large pandas dataframe; sample shown below :

I want to evenly distribute the "Good" flag between the ranges; so that each score range has equal number of goods.

```
Score   Good
100    0
100    0
100    0
300    0
400    0
400    0
600    1
600    1
600    0
650    0
650    0
650    1
700    1
770    1
770    1
800    0
890    1
890    1
```

Sample Output:

```
bins       Goods
100 - 600   2
650-700     2
770-800     2
> 890       2
```

I tried using  `pd.cut` and `pd.qcut` but didn't able to figure this out.

Comment: when you want to divide your dataset into groups of 10, is count of all goods multiple of 10? Otherwise, it is unclear where to divide group.

Comment: Hi @Panda , please ignore the note ( I have edited my question). I just need to define the bin range in a way that each bins will have equal number of goods.

Comment: @Ash, did you consider the corner case when a big percentage of items are on same bin and other items are distributed over other bins? For example, in above data if there are 4 items for score = 600, then what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [`qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) and [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
# split in defined number of bins considering only Good == 1
N = 4
bins = pd.qcut(df.query('Good == 1')['Score'], N).cat.categories.tolist()

# extend min/max of first/last bins
bins[0] = pd.Interval(df['Score'].min()-0.01, bins[0].right)
bins[-1] = pd.Interval(bins[-1].left,  df['Score'].max())

# now we have 4 bins with "equal"* number of Good == 1
# (*in the limit of being able to split equally)
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df['Score'], bins=pd.IntervalIndex(bins))
```

*NB. this doesn't require the data to be sorted.*

Example:

```
    Score  Good             bin
0     100     0  (99.99, 637.5] # bin 1
1     100     0  (99.99, 637.5]
2     100     0  (99.99, 637.5]
3     300     0  (99.99, 637.5]
4     400     0  (99.99, 637.5]
5     400     0  (99.99, 637.5]
6     600     1  (99.99, 637.5]
7     600     1  (99.99, 637.5]
8     600     0  (99.99, 637.5]

9     650     0  (637.5, 735.0] # bin 2
10    650     0  (637.5, 735.0]
11    650     1  (637.5, 735.0]
12    700     1  (637.5, 735.0]

13    770     1  (735.0, 800.0] # bin 3
14    770     1  (735.0, 800.0]
15    800     0  (735.0, 800.0]

16    890     1  (800.0, 890.0] # bin 4
17    890     1  (800.0, 890.0]
```

Example with `N = 2`:

```
    Score  Good             bin
0     100     0  (99.99, 735.0] # bin 1
1     100     0  (99.99, 735.0]
2     100     0  (99.99, 735.0]
3     300     0  (99.99, 735.0]
4     400     0  (99.99, 735.0]
5     400     0  (99.99, 735.0]
6     600     1  (99.99, 735.0]
7     600     1  (99.99, 735.0]
8     600     0  (99.99, 735.0]
9     650     0  (99.99, 735.0]
10    650     0  (99.99, 735.0]
11    650     1  (99.99, 735.0]
12    700     1  (99.99, 735.0]

13    770     1  (735.0, 890.0] # bin 2
14    770     1  (735.0, 890.0]
15    800     0  (735.0, 890.0]
16    890     1  (735.0, 890.0]
17    890     1  (735.0, 890.0]
```

With `N = 3` (not a divisor of the number of Goods), this tries to split as fairly as possible, leaving I've category with 1 less Good:

```
    Score  Good               bin
0     100     0  (99.99, 666.667] # bin 1
1     100     0  (99.99, 666.667]
2     100     0  (99.99, 666.667]
3     300     0  (99.99, 666.667]
4     400     0  (99.99, 666.667]
5     400     0  (99.99, 666.667]
6     600     1  (99.99, 666.667]
7     600     1  (99.99, 666.667]
8     600     0  (99.99, 666.667]
9     650     0  (99.99, 666.667]
10    650     0  (99.99, 666.667]
11    650     1  (99.99, 666.667]

12    700     1  (666.667, 770.0] # bin 2
13    770     1  (666.667, 770.0]
14    770     1  (666.667, 770.0]

15    800     0    (770.0, 890.0] # bin 3
16    890     1    (770.0, 890.0] # only 2 Good
17    890     1    (770.0, 890.0]
```

#### aggregation

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Score'], bins=pd.IntervalIndex(bins)))['Good'].sum()
```

Output:

```
Score
(99.99, 637.5]    2
(637.5, 735.0]    2
(735.0, 800.0]    2
(800.0, 890.0]    2
Name: Good, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi @mozway. Tested and can confirm ; it works like a charm and that's exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
data = [[100, 0], [100, 0], [100, 0], [300, 0], [400, 0], [400, 0], [600, 1], [600, 1], [600, 0], 
        [650, 0], [650, 0], [650, 1], [700, 1], [770, 1], [770, 1], [800, 0], [890, 1], [890, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Score', 'Good'])
```

**Code**

```
n = 4
grouper = pd.cut(df.sort_values(['Score', 'Good'], ascending=[1, 0])['Good'].cumsum(), bins=n)
mapper = df.groupby(grouper)['Score'].agg([min, max]).astype('str').apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x), axis=1)
df1 = df.groupby(grouper)['Good'].sum()
df1.index = df1.index.map(mapper).astype('str')
df1 = df1.reset_index(name='1').set_axis(['bins', 'Good'], axis=1)
df1.iloc[-1, 0] = '>= ' + df1.iloc[-1, 0].split('-')[0]
```

`df1`

```
    bins    Good
0   100-600 2
1   650-700 2
2   770-800 2
3   >= 890  2
```

I'll try to find easier way

Comment: You have pre-decided the number of bins to 4. The ask is to decide a range with equal number of items. This ask is very subjective to the data. There can be a corner case when a big percentage of items are on same bin and other items are distributed over other bins.

Comment: I made this because he asked to divide it into 10 group at first. he fixed it later, but I thought it wouldn't make much of a difference. I thought that he would not have asked to divide into all divisible combinations. I thought that he wanted to divide group by aappropriately specified number.

Comment: thanks @Panda, that's pretty much what I needed. Thank you; may you add a bit of explanation please, will help me able to understand the logic better ; answer upvoted

Comment: as we see, It is not easy to explain the code. I want to help too but I don't know how expain. so i just modified it a bit for you can change `n`

Comment: @Ash i edited my answer a bit. test with `n=2`

Comment: Hi @Panda , I think the above code has some issue. It's only fetches1 record as an output when I test it with other bins like  n = 4

Comment: @Ash The first time was like that, and the modified code wasn't. and I modified it again more simply. Test with n=2 and n=4

Comment: Sorry my bad; it works now